# Вещественные числа

Tags: c++, длинная-арифметика

Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека, в которой реализовано следующее:
вот, например, есть double - он хранит мантиссу определенной длины, а надо чтобы эта длина мантиссы в зависимости от ситуации динамически увеличивалась (если она полностью не влезла), ну и чтобы выполнялись стандартные операции.

Comment: В средах типа Maple или Mathcad используются более сложные структуры для хранения чисел. Например, число можно хранить как формулу. Вот, скажем, что Вы будете делать с числом корень из двух? Его без потери точности как значение типа float, double или прочих 'вещественных' типов не представить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google на c++ bigfloat выдает 14000 результатов поиска.

Comment: gmp, т.е. gnu mp.